# ADO.NET работа с DataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, ado.net

Задача такова: `DataGridView` заполненный названиями таблиц базы данных, нужно при нажатии на ячейку `DataGridView`, содержащую название таблицы, сформировать запрос, который выведет содержимое этой таблицы в другой `DataGridView`. Использую MS SQL Server. Хотел попробовать с помощью переменной указать название таблиц, но не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Извлечь данные из конкретного столбца можно так:

```
string tn = DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["Имя_Таблицы"].Value.ToString();
```

Не совсем ясно, на каком этапе у вас трудности.

Comment: var tn = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Имя_Таблицы"].Value.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

По событию клика на ячейку пишем соответствующий обработчик. А вообще еще рано что-то говорить, покажи лучше код, где ты формируешь запрос, дабы не быть голословным.